# How to pass class instance and all it does to another class in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I am writing a script with file structure as below:

- main.py
- field_integration.py

The **field_integration.py**:

```
import numpy as np
class Integration():
    def __init__(self, param1, param2):

        self.p1 = param1
        self.p2 = param2

        self.derive(self.p2)

    def derive(self, param2):

        self.pp1 = 2/self.p1
        self.pp2 = param2/3

        self.another_function_inside_the_class()
    
    def another_function_inside_the_class(self):
        print('OK')
```

The **main.py**:

```
from field_int import Integration
from fitting import Autofit

ppp1 = 1
ppp2 = 2

profile = Integration(ppp1, ppp2)

ppp5 = 3
fitt = Autofit(ppp5)

y_pre_fitted = fitt.pre_fitting(profile.p2, 0)
```

The **fitting.py**:

```
from field_int import Integration

class Autofit(Integration):
    def __init__(self, param5):
        self.p5 = param5
        
    def pre_fitting(self, param2, param3):
        Integration.derive(param2)
        print(param3)
```

While **fitting.py** `pre_fitting` method works well when directly in **main.py**, here it throws the TypeError: *line 8, in pre_fitting
Integration.derive(param2)
TypeError: derive() missing 1 required positional argument: 'param2'*.

If I change the line to have `Integration.derive(self, param2)`, it throws the AttributeError: *'Autofit' object has no attribute 'p1'*

How then can I recreate the functionality of the code from the **main.py** inside another file? Should I move it to the same file as the class definition I instantiate? I am quite a noob concerning classes, I heard something about inheritance but I was only beating my head against the wall, because I don't understand how that would help me.

Comment: With `Integration.derive(param2)` you call that method as if it is a static/class method, but it is an instance method, so you should do `instance = Integration(); instance.derive(param2)`

Comment: Wouldn't that create a new instance? I wanted to pass an existing instance named ```profile``` and use its variables and methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are subclassing `Integration`, you can just call the function with `self` or `super()`. `super()` can be used when the subclass also overrides the superclass' method and we need to call the superclass method instead of the subclass. But in your case, you are not overriding so a simple `self` call should suffice, so -

```py
from field_int import Integration

class Autofit(Integration):
    def __init__(self, param5):
        self.p5 = param5
        
    def pre_fitting(self, param2, param3):
        self.derive(param2)
        print(param3)
```

On another note, it is usually a good idea to also Initialise the superclass using `super()` such as -

```py
from field_int import Integration

class Autofit(Integration):
    def __init__(self, param1, param2, param5):
        super().__init__(param1, param2)
        self.p5 = param5
        
    def pre_fitting(self, param2, param3):
        self.derive(param2)
        print(param3)
```

Because now if you call the `derive` method without the `super().__init__` the values for `p1` and `p2` required in the `derive` method will not be defined. So better to call `__init__` on superclass before the method call.

### Update

An alternate approach to what you want to achieve without using inheritance (if you are not extending the functionality of `Integration` class) -

**fitting.py**

```py
from field_int import Integration

class Autofit():
    def __init__(self, integration: Integration, param5):
        self.p5 = param5
        self.integration = integration
        
    def pre_fitting(self, param2, param3):
        self.integration.derive(param2)
        print(param3)
```

**main.py**

```py
from field_int import Integration
from fitting import Autofit

ppp1 = 1
ppp2 = 2

profile = Integration(ppp1, ppp2)

ppp5 = 3
fitt = Autofit(profile, ppp5)

y_pre_fitted = fitt.pre_fitting(profile.p2, 0)
```

Comment: It doesn't work, though. What is this object: ```integration: Integration```?

Comment: Ah i see, I am sorry I misunderstood as __init__ call. Let me update the answer

Comment: @RadekD Update now

Comment: I don't think `super()` is needed here (for calling `derive`); `AutoFit` doesn't override `derive` (unless OP omitted something), so a simple `self.derive(param2)` would do the trick.

Comment: @ShadowRanger thanks updated the answer with explanation

Comment: Now it shows error in main.py:    fitt = Autofit(ppp5)
TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'param2' and 'param5'``` Wonder why...

Comment: OK. It worked. Is there any way to not having to pass all the arguments again?

Comment: because now you need to pass 3 arguments, for initialising the `Integration` superclass too. Try `fitt = Autofit(ppp1, ppp2, ppp5)`.  Also, i am unsure why you are using inheritance here, you could just create an object of the `Integration` class and pass it as a parameter in the `Autofit` init method. Then call the derive using that object.

Comment: Ha! This is the best one! You can add it to the answer, I guess, because it allows to omit typing all arguments of given instance... :)

Comment: Added update to the answer on how to make it work without using inheritance.